# Incorrect Vim formatting in text file

Tags: vim

I think this issue happens only in text file(s). So very often, but not always, when I open text file with vim, there are new line spaces inside file, even though I don't have anything inside real text file.

If I tried to remove it, or modify anything, everything will screw up, so I need to reopen file. It looks like this:

[image: output]

Couldn't find on the net about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether this also happens in GVIM. If it only appears in the terminal, you have a wrong value of `$TERM`, or (less likely) corrupt / wrong termcap definitions. Most terminals should understand a value of

```
$ export TERM=xterm
```

Comment: It does not happen in gvim, so how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: What terminal emulator do you use, and what is the value of `$TERM`?!

Comment: It says xterm, but before I did `export TERM=xterm` as you said. This bug still happens. I use zsh, default terminal I think.